# Mysql replicacion BD

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]mi problema es el siguiente
cree una replica de una base de datos en mysql,pero cuando le hago la incersion a mi servidor maestro  desde Worbench o phpmyadmin si se actualizan los datos en el esclavo.
Mi sorpresa es que cuando inserto desde una programa solo se ven en el servidor maestro y en el esclavo no se actualiza ningún dato

**SLAVE**

```
Slave_IO_State  = waiting for master to send event  
Master_Host    =   172.16.30.253
Master_User    = mantenimiento
Master_Port     =3306
Connect_Retry = 60
Master_Log_File=  mysql-bin.000001
Read_Master_Log_Pos= 3266
Relay_Log_File = MANTTO-PC-relay-bin.000002
Relay_Log_Pos = 1987
Relay_Master_Log_File = mysql-bin.000001
Slave_IO_Running =yes
Slave_SQL_Running =yes
Replicate_Do_DB =
Replicate_Ignore_DB
Replicate_Do_Table
Replicate_Ignore_Table
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table
Last_Errno =0
Last_Error   =0
Skip_Counter=0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos =3266
Relay_Log_Space =2198
Until_Condition = none 
Until_Log_File
Until_Log_Pos
Master_SSL_Allowed =no
Master_SSL_CA_File
Master_SSL_CA_Path
```

**MASTER**

```
File = mysql-bin.000001
Position = 3266
Binlog_Do_DB = servicios
Binlog_Ignore_DB
```

Comment: Podrías agregar más información al respecto, comenzando con un SHOW MASTER STATUS en el master y SHOW PROCESSLIST en el esclavo por ejemplo.

Comment: Servidor maestro                                                                                              File = mysql-bin.000001                                                                                                        Position = 3266
Binlog_Do_DB = servicios
Binlog_Ignore_DB =

Comment: Slave_IO_State  = waiting for master to send event                   
Master_Host    =   172.16.30.253
Master_User    = mantenimiento
Master_Port     =3306
Connect_Retry = 60
Master_Log_File=  mysql-bin.000001
Read_Master_Log_Pos= 3266

Comment: Relay_Log_File = MANTTO-PC-relay-bin.000002
Relay_Log_Pos = 1987
Relay_Master_Log_File = mysql-bin.000001
Slave_IO_Running =yes
Slave_SQL_Running =yes
Replicate_Do_DB =
Replicate_Ignore_DB
Replicate_Do_Table
Replicate_Ignore_Table
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table
Last_Errno =0
Last_Error   =0
Skip_Counter=0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos =3266
Relay_Log_Space =2198
Until_Condition = none 
Until_Log_File
Until_Log_Pos
Master_SSL_Allowed =no

Comment: id =  1878, host=MANTTO-PC:50846,DB=NULL ,Command= binlogDump,Time=83685, state =Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for b, info = null

Comment: Doc, te recomiendo que todo eso lo pongas editando tu publicación en lugar de los comentarios.

Comment: Gracias dame un segundo para ponerlo mas entendible